# Sonarqube task in Gradle does not produce test coverage

Tags: unit-testing, gradle, sonarqube, code-coverage, sonarqube-scan

I have multi-project Gradle script. I added to the root project:

```
buildscript {
    repositories{
        ...
    }

    dependencies { classpath("org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:2.2.1") }
}

apply plugin: org.sonarqube.gradle.SonarQubePlugin

sonarqube {
    properties {
        property "sonar.junit.reportsPath", "$projectDir/build/test-results/test"
        property "sonar.host.url", "http://localhost:9000"
        property "sonar.verbose", "true"
    }
}
```

Sonarqube shows the correct number of tests, but coverage is 0.

I use Gradle 3.0, Java 1.8.0_45, Sonarqube 6.1.

Gradle console shows many "Class not found" messages.

Gradle console also shows message:

> "Reports path contains no files matching TEST-.*.xml :
>   myPath\build\test-results\test"

, which is correct, since that particular project does not have any tests.

Comment: Are you expecting the analysis to produce _and then consume_ the test coverage report?

Comment: I expect instructions on how to produce test coverage in Sonarqube.

Answer (score 3):

In my child project, I have:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: "jacoco"

jacocoTestReport {
    reports {
        xml.enabled = true
    }
}

check.dependsOn jacocoTestReport
```

Run Gradle task "sonarqube" of the root project.

Comment: I think it would be better to replace the last line with `test.finalizedBy jacocoTestReport`, since Jacoco needs to run `test` anyway.

Answer (score 2):

No SonarQube Analyzer or plugin executes your tests or the coverage calculation for you. You must do those things before analysis and feed the resulting report(s) into your analysis.

Comment: An example would be helpful.

Comment: Link to "tutorial for coverage integration" in your blog is broken: http://www.sonarqube.org/manage-code-coverage-by-unit-tests-with-sonar/